# Drawing on an image & implementing AspectFill for CGRect. Can it be done?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, cgrect

The following image is a screen grab from an iPad 9.7 simulator, showing the circles overlayed on an underlying live preview. (The live camera view is not there because it's on the Simulator)
On any sort of iPhone the circles clip off at the screen edges, but on the iPad you can see the clipping. I'm sure this is an AspectFit or AspectFill problem but I can't find a solution. Somehow, the code isn't seeing the correct iPad screen size?

This is the code that does it. Firstly the call, then the functions. It all works fine, except for that clipping...

```
        //=======================================
        // draw the circles on the image then return
    imgOverlay.image = self.drawCirclesOnImage(fromImage: nil, targetSize: imgOverlay.bounds.size)
```

and now we have the two functions that draw the circles.

```
    func getImageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {

    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight))
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}

func drawCirclesOnImage(fromImage: UIImage? = nil, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {

    if fromImage == nil && targetSize == CGSize.zero {
        return nil
    }

    var tmpimg: UIImage?

    if targetSize == CGSize.zero {
        tmpimg = fromImage
    } else {
        tmpimg = getImageWithColor(color: UIColor.clear, size: targetSize)
    }
    guard let img = tmpimg else {
        return nil
    }
    let imageSize = img.size

    let scale: CGFloat = 0
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, scale)
    img.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)


    let w = imageSize.width
    //let w = screenWidth
    let h = imageSize.height
    //let h = screenHeight
    print("Width 1: \(w) Height 1: \(h)")

    let midX = imageSize.width / 2
    let midY = imageSize.height / 2
    //let midX = screenWidth / 2
    //let midY = screenHeight / 2

    // red circles - radius in %
    let circleRads = [ 0.07, 0.13, 0.17, 0.22, 0.29, 0.36, 0.40, 0.48, 0.60, 0.75 ]

    // center "dot" - radius is 1.5%
    var circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: midX,y: midY), radius: CGFloat(w * 0.010), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)

    UIColor.white.setFill()
    circlePath.stroke()
    circlePath.fill()

    lineColor = getLineColor(color: color)
    lineColor?.setStroke()


    for pct in circleRads {

        let rad = w * CGFloat(pct)

        circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: midX, y: midY), radius: CGFloat(rad), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)

        circlePath.lineWidth = 2.5
        circlePath.stroke()
    }

    // draw text time stamp on image
    let now = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
    let dateString = formatter.string(from: now)
   // print(dateString)
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
    let attrs = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 26)!, NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]
    let string = dateString
    string.draw(with: CGRect(x: 12, y: 38, width: 448, height: 448), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attrs, context: nil)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can take 2 images, one background one to draw and then merge them when you are done.

Comment: Yes, I have done that in the rest of the program thanks. What I need here is to have those circles drawn completely, not clipped off at the edge, you notice that the Screen image in the screen capture, is much wider than the red circles.

Comment: You ImageView's Frame is that much only ? Or the image you posted is after merging if you are merging 2 images ?

Comment: The image is not merged. The circle is overlayed on a blank preview layer. The blank layer is the iPad width, the Circle overlay is not as wide. It's being clipped at the sides?